# Show diacritics in the printer spooler

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, subprocess, pyqt5

I have this code

```
os.chdir(documents_dir)
file  = self.myListWidget.item(0)

args = '"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\gs\\\\gs9.52\\\\bin\\\\gswin64c" ' \
       '-dBATCH ' \
       '-dNOPAUSE ' \
       '-dFitPage ' \
       '-sOutputFile="%printer%{}" ' \
       '-c "mark /UserSettings <</DocumentName ({})>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" '.format(ptr_name, file)
ghostscript = args + os.path.abspath(file)
subprocess.call(ghostscript, shell=True)
```

The `file` contains diacritics which is incorrectly displayed in the printer spooler.

The file is taken from here:

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Downloads")
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
  QListWidgetItem(file, self.myListWidget)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: From what you provide I really can't understand what's the correlation between PyQt and the printing spooler. Can at least show us what those "diacritics" are? Is the problem in printing or displaying the file name? Have you tried to print that file by setting the file name manually? Please, be more specific.

Comment: @musicamante The file is something like 'áčřš.pdf'. I'm not sure if it is important to provide that it is in the listWidget and arises from glob.glob.

Comment: The file is printed without problems, but on a display of the printer the characters are displayed incorrectly. Unfortunaly, I don't have the printer here to write you what's displayed.

Comment: So the problem is that the file name is shown with wrong characters? If that's so, *where* is it shown like that? Is the name shown correctly in the QListWidgetItem? What system are you on? Possibly provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante Yes, it is shown correctly in the QListWidgetItem. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately if you cannot provide a reproducible example it is a bit hard to understand what's going on.